# SQL Server RLS vs Oracle FGAC

Tags: sql-server, oracle, security, row-level-security

What is the difference between SQL Server RLS and Oracle FGAC. How to decide which one to go for? We already have both the products in place and teams to support the products.

Comment: Does your choice between these two products really come down to this one feature, and not license cost, support, ease of operation, third-party tools, available expertise .. or any number of other considerations? Perhaps you should edit the question to amplify your deliberations.

Comment: RLS is a feature of SQL Server. FGAC is a feature of Oracle Database. Depends on which database you use.

Comment: Both achieve the same: fine-grained access control, more broadly known as attribute-based access control (ABAC). It's not just about databases. It also applies to APIs and more. Oracle VPD is Oracle's way of implementing ABAC/FGAC. Other vendors e.g. MS SQL have their own ways. There are 3rd party products that sit on top e.g. Informatica's DDM or Axiomatics' SmartGuard.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Oracle, but these the seems to do different things.

RLS is row-level security. I.e., you see this row, but not that row.

FGAC (fine-grained access control) seems to be about auditing, i.e., "I can see that you did this modification yesterday". That would be more comparable to the Server Audit feature in SQL Server. (Please correct me if I'm wrong, those who know about FGAC.)

Comment: I'm assuming the OP ment FGAC (Fine Grain Access Control) not FGAS.

Comment: @MichaelKutz Yes, FGAC